# Publishing a Unity game to Android/iPhone

Tags: unity, android-studio

How can I publish a game that I made in Unity onto Android and iPhone? How do I generate the Android/iPhone binaries?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? How much do you already know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Unity, if you select *File > Build Settings...* you'll bring up this window:

[image]

You can click on any platform and select "*Switch Platform*" which slightly changes your development environment.  Some assets might re-import and [Unity Platform Directives](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) in your code like `if #UNITY_ANDROID` will become useful.

From this same menu, clicking "*Player Settings...*" will provide more customization options in the *Inspector*.

When you're confident the project is in the state you want, click *Build*.  For Android, you can follow this Manual to help with [Building for Android](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-BuildProcess.html).  With IOS, Unity will give you an .xcodeproj which you will then need XCode to compile and deploy to IOS devices (you can't do this without a Mac or without doing some illegal work-arounds).

Note that this is for "Building" to these platforms and not "Publishing".  If you have a completed project and would like to publish it to Android and IOS's markets, that's not something to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Google Play Developer Console: https://play.google.com/apps/publish/ 
App Store Developer Page: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/

They both need registration fees.

Comment: @ashes999 He says "how can i publish", i don't see any relation between "workflows for a Unity game" and "publishing".

Comment: @ashes999 As composer of answer mentioned at last paragraph, that answer doesn't give any information about "publishing", but it's completely about "building to target platform". These are different.